Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration on powershell is complaining that no RDS service exists, even if it exists
This is an issue I already found the answer after many hours. But it is so crazy that I want to share my result.
I wanted in windows use the powershell command
Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration

to define UDS files for RDS (remote desktop). But it did not work, as it complained that I need RDS service first being setup.
My German error message:

Die Remotedesktopdienste-Bereitstellung ist auf "EX01.foobar.local"
nicht vorhanden

But wait, it was already setup!
As admin (different user) I see it in Server-Manager!

Finaly the answer is:

The service user (which I use for winrm), must have added the terminal servers as manageable servers first to his Server-Manager!

How can this be? Server-Manager is a GUI tool and I just want to add UDS parameters.
The crazy thing is, that somehow the Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration interacts with the Server-Manager instance of the user who is executing it. Not a pure command line behaviour.
My personal solution is, that I manipulate a special XML file of the Server-Manager, where the added manageable machines are listed.
\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\ServerManager\ServerList.xml

Shame on MS for this way to alter a service.
Hope this helps someone else one day.

I'm sure this will help someone else one day, not sure why it's such a shame to have to modify a configuration file to make something more fine tuned. There might be a correlated github where MS dev and community that assist can have this request submitted to make a PowerShell cmdlet change the parameters and such as the correlated configuration file/XML. If you poke around, you might find something where you can submit such feedback for consideration, and there might figure out another workaround or two as well to this issue you experienced.

Thanks for your feedback. The point is, the Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration is made to configure a RDS session, which is managed by a service. The service has nothing todo with the Server-Management GUI. So the expectation is simple: The command shall communicate with the service to alter the RDS settings. BUT its not working like that; it goes over the user related settings of the Server-Manager (a GUI to manage services). Wrong architecture. Imagine on Linux if you would only be able to change network settings if GUI is running - would be strange.

Gotcha! +1 on both... nice workaround! Does seem like a bizarre bug, like something cannot be changed to be effective, unless an instance of it is running in memory first before it saves for running configuration on next instance once killed and reopened, unless you change the config per the command if it is running, etc. If I get any time, I will play around to see if I notice any other observations with those operations and detail you've provided. Good job and points!

The main reason why I used Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration, was to define profile disks for users. Meanwhile I had to recognize that it is kind of deprecated and wise to do this with fslogix. So even if the feature exists, better ignore it and use fslogix, which is more flexible and it works with GPOs.
